# c# get text from datagrid of another applicaion

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I'm looking for a help with getting data from datagridview.
I have a app' which has a datagridview but it doesn't allow me to copy data from it. `Ctrl+C` Is diabled. But I can select the datacells `Ctrl+A` and I can change the cell selection with `TAB`.
I need a help in getting the text from it. I have classname of the application `WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.bf7771_r12_ad1` and classname and instance of the datagridview `CLASS:WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.bf7771_r12_ad1;INSTANCE:1`

Your help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You need to set the ClipboardCopyMode property of the DataGridView to allow copying. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.clipboardcopymode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: But I can't edit the other application

Comment: Then you can't read from it.  As a workaround, and depending on how much work you want to put in, and how hacky you want the solution to be, you could look in to writing a test application using TestStack from White (http://www.teststack.net/blog/introducing-teststack) which _may_ allow you to scrape the information from the app.